# Hyperref's FitH is not the same as bookmark's FitH

Tags: hyperref, pdfpages, bookmarks

I've got a problem making sure all my bookmark links in the PDF file act the same in Adobe Acrobat. The following is my MWE,

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitH}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\bookmarksetup{view=FitH}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[link]{cover.pdf}
\bookmark[dest=cover.pdf.1]{Cover}

\chapter{Introduction}
\end{document}
```

The problem is the first bookmark created shows me the whole page on my screen as opposed to filling the width of the window with the page. The second bookmark acts as required.

I want all the bookmarks to open as defined in `pdfstartview=FitH`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
\includepdf[link,linkfit={FitH 0}]{cover.pdf}
```

which specifies the target link fit to be `H`orizontal. Note that the default settings for an `\include`d `pdf` is `linkfit=fit` (similar to what you experience in your example).